# How to define rules match pattern regex max 6 character?

Tags: regex, yii2

I have following rule in my model classs

```
[['kode_pos', 'p_kode_pos'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{0,6}+$/'],
```

Above code doesn't work indicate with i input anything and no error appear in my input field.

but with this rule

```
[['kode_pos', 'p_kode_pos'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/'],
```

It works contain only letter,number, space and error will appear if input special character. but how to define max 6 char?

Comment: Try pattern `/^[\w ]{0,6}$/`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this code

```
[['kode_pos', 'p_kode_pos'], 'string', 'max' => 6],
```

Comment: This allows other characters than listed in the pattern like `-`, `,` and so on.

Comment: gave it a try like what you say but It work like expected, when I input `-`, `,` it show error.

Comment: There is no way the `string` rule with `max` parameter only can result in error when you type `-` or `,`

Answer (score 0):

Use this (remove plus)

```
[['kode_pos', 'p_kode_pos'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{0,6}$/'],
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work like expected,
just type 123 and it show invalid, type letter less than 6 char it show invalid
and I can type more than 6 char.
anyway just solved it.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, you need to add first number of range, you can skip second one, not the other way around. So `{0,6}` and not `{,6}`

Answer (score 0):

Use two different validator

```
[['fieldName'], 'string', 'max' => 6,'tooLong' => 'field exceeded max length'],
[['fieldName'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/','message'=>'invalid format'],
```